# How do I find out the credentials I used for a Samba share?

Tags: ubuntu, samba, nas

We have a NAS attached to our wireless router which appears to run samba, our Ubuntu laptop connects fine to this and works well. However, we can't remember the credentials used to set this up our new machines.

I assume these credentials are stored in a file somewhere in ubuntu, any ideas where it may be?

It was initially connected using the connect to server screen.

Answer (score 2):

They are kept in GNOME Keyring, accessible through `seahorse`.

Comment: if it is something like Netgear ReadyNAS then it will have a built in website that you can go to to access the directory shares, user permissions and other misc stuff. Here you should be able to set up the access credentials for your users across different machines.